# Converting RPC interface to REST

Tags: rest, rpc

I have used RPC for years but am now in a situation where we must use REST.  I am trying to understand the differences between the two and how one might be superior to the other.  As such, I have read a lot of articles trying to fully understand the subtleties.  So far, it seems good but there are a few slight problems.

I understand (at least I think I do), the general idea of sharing things as a resource which is acquired by use of the verbs GET, PUT, etc.  This maps well to most server access concepts, but there are other ideas which do not map so easily.  For example, I need to inform the server to download a gravatar image and store it.  I'm not sure how that fits into a RESTful endpoint.

Please note that I know how to just do RPC disguised as REST, but I'm not interested in that.  I want to do this the "REST way", if for no other reason than to understand what that way actually is.

Comment: And what actually you are asking - how to implement using REST adding gravatar image to user profile?

Comment: No, I'm asking more generally how to represent procedures in REST which do not easily map to the typical GET, PUT, etc verbiage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in most cases RPC style services are good mapping to REST. So, CRUD operations are mapped anywhere good. Anyway we can at first stage identify contract methods map them to URIs and to different HTTP Verbs. Second stage is to introduce resources, may be they are present in form of DTO object.

Anyway road map from RPC to REST (most likely Level 2) is good described on Richardson Maturity Model (RMM):

- **Level 0:** SOAP, XML RPC, POX, Single URI
- **Level 1:** URI Tunnelling, Many URIs, Single verb
- **Level 2:** Many URIs, many verbs, CRUD services (e.g. Amazon S3)
- **Level 3:** Level 2 + Hypermedia RESTful Services

More on RMM here:

http://code.google.com/p/implementing-rest/wiki/RMM
http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

But seems to me you are already knowing that. So what about complex scenarios. There are a lot of them. As example from question:

> For example, I need to inform the server to download a gravatar image
>   and store it. I'm not sure how that fits into a RESTful endpoint.

I do not think that it's mapping hardly to REST. And all depends from nuances. As example why not to do it while registering user when user has selected "gravatar" option. Or why not to have GET http://bookslirarysample.com/users/15/gravatar. It's not problem for REST.

But maybe you assume not only REST endpoint or how to say server. Sure, under gravatar functionality is not only REST call. On server could be message bus, your REST server sends message through it. Special "downloader" service will receive this message, download image, store it and save to user oject with some id. REST is not decling huge server infrusturuture behind of it. Behind REST facade could be complex, enterprise level event driven architecture. And it's not a problem for REST.

Anyway there more advanced scenarios. Like notifications aggregation, transactions, security etc. Many of the, are good described in book of Jim Webber:

[REST in Practice: Hypermedia and Systems Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805829)